# How can I pass pagination data and array from controller laravel to vue component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-5.6

My controller like this :

```
public function index()
{
    $products = $this->product->list(); 
    dd($products);
    return view('admin.product.index',compact('products'));
}
```

The result of `dd($products);` like this : https://postimg.org/image/w39usbfrv/

My view blade laravel like this :

```
<section class="content">
    <product-list :products="{{$products}}" test="test"></product-list>
</section>
```

My vue component product list like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="box">
        ...
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['products','test'],
        mounted(){
            console.log(this.test)
            console.log(this.products)
        }
        ...
    }
</script>
```

If I run the code, on the console just display result of`console.log(this.test)`

The result of `console.log(this.products)` is not display

Why it not display?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why this question is downvote?

Comment: Is there no one can help?

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider how to access data within the vue component. Instead of having the controller pass the data along with the view, make a request from the client to fetch the data. Change the  route method to respond to both ajax and regular requests:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json(['products'  => $this->product->list()]);
    }

    return view('admin.product.index'); 
}
```

From the client, use `axios` to fetch the data:

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios

  export default { 
    mounted() {
        axios.get('/products').then(response => {
          this.products = response.data.products
        }
     },
     data () {
        return {
          products: []
        }
      }
    ... 
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: I know it. But here I just want to try the another way